# Maven - Load jar contained in dependency

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to maven and I know that this is a common problem but can't make my project work.

I have an jar A which contains only a manifest and a lib folder with a jar B.

I'm able to add A as dependency in this way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>A</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</compile>
</dependency>
```

Maven successfully builds but at runtime I get a ClassNotFoundException for a class contained in B.

So, how can I include B?

My plugins section is like this:

```
<plugins>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

</plugins>
```

Comment: You need to add JARs A and B to a Maven repository.  You won't have a /lib folder anymore.  Look at mvn import command.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760968/maven-add-jar-with-dependencies-as-a-dependecy

Comment: @duffymo there's no way to add just the project A?

Comment: @Taylor it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should create two project A and B. Having module B I would install it in local Maven repo (mvn install) and the pull it like regular Maven dependency.

Probably your IDE see B's classes as you have jar in lib folder.

Comment: Yes, in this case I would surely solve the issue. But this is a workaround, my goal was to include just the project A