# Pull dependencies as a jar in maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar, package, dependencies

Is there a way I can pull some specific jar directly as a dependency defined in maven?

I have a maven project which has some internal and external dependencies. I am hosting this project on a maven registry so I can consume it in other projects. I am creating a jar and as well as creating "jar-with-dependencies" using the maven-assembly plugin in my project. Then I am hosting this on the maven repository where it has the pom, jar, and jar-with-dependencies all hosted.

In the other maven project, I want to pull the above maven project as a dependency. When I am trying to directly define it as a dependency as mentioned below, it is trying to pull the dependencies of the original project too in which some of the internal ones it could not find. Is there a way so that it can pull the hosted jar-with-dependencies directly or some other solution to this problem.
P.S. I do not want to host all those internal dependencies directly on the maven registry.

**Update**: I tried adding dependency with the help of the maven classifier to point to jar-with-dependencies. But it still does not resolve the issue

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.myproject.project</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-java-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven - Add jar-with-dependencies as a dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760968/maven-add-jar-with-dependencies-as-a-dependency)

Comment: A dependency  can be scoped so even if required at compile time it is not needed at runtime.